TextFSMTemplateError with Cisco show env output
I have a file named show_env.fsm with these contents:
Value TEMPERATURE_MODULE (\d+)
Value TEMPERATURE_SENSOR ([^\s\(\)]+)
Value TEMPERATURE_MAJOR_THRESH (\d+)
Value TEMPERATURE_MINOR_THRESH (\d+)
Value TEMPERATURE_CURRENT (\d+)
Value TEMPERATURE_STATUS (\S+)

Start
  ^Temperature:\s*$$ -> Temperature

Temperature
  ^Module\s+Sensor\s+MajorThresh\s+MinorThres\s+CurTemp\s+Status
  ^${TEMPERATURE_MODULE}\s+${TEMPERATURE_SENSOR}(\s*\(\S+\))?\s+${TEMPERATURE_MAJOR_THRESH}\s+${TEMPERATURE_MINOR_THRESH}\s+${TEMPERATURE_CURRENT}\s+${TEMPERATURE_STATUS}\s* -> Record
  ^\s*\(Celsius\)\s+\(Celsius\)
  ^-+\s*$$
  ^\s*$$
  ^. -> Error

I'm parsing this output:
Temperature:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Module   Sensor        MajorThresh   MinorThres   CurTemp     Status
                       (Celsius)     (Celsius)    (Celsius)         
--------------------------------------------------------------------
3        Left   (s5)     60              42          29         Ok         
3        MOSFET (s8)     80              60          41         Ok                        
5        MOSFET (s9)     80              60          38         Ok   

I get a textfsm.parser.TextFSMTemplateError error when I parse that output.
This is my python code:
from textfsm import TextFSM

output = open('output.txt').read()

with open('show_env.fsm') as template:
    fsm = TextFSM(template)
    results_list = fsm.ParseText(output)

What do I need to do to fix this?

I think there was a bug in textfsm 1.1.2, please upgrade to version 1.1.3.
This works for me with textfsm 1.1.3:
from textfsm import TextFSM

output = open('output.txt').read()

with open('show_env.fsm') as template:
    fsm = TextFSM(template)
    results_list = fsm.ParseText(output)

print(results_list)

It prints this (with some formatting):
[
 ['3', 'Left', '60', '42', '29', 'Ok'],
 ['3', 'MOSFET', '80', '60', '41', 'Ok'],
 ['5', 'MOSFET', '80', '60', '38', 'Ok']
]

Also for long lists of Values, consider using fsm.ParseTextToDicts(output), which will give you a list of dicts instead of a list of lists (which gets cumbersome to maintain as your list of values gets longer).
